# Serialize a JS object for offline use

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

There is a complex object (lots of properties of different types.. arrays, functions, strings etc.) created inside of my app and it's creation is the only thing standing between being and not being able to use that part of the app offline. My idea is to cache it in localStorage and then restore it in offline mode.

I tried with the obvious candidates, JSON.stringify() and .toString(), none of which produce the serialization needed. Maybe my whole approach is flawed.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You can't serialize Javascript functions.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline

Comment: There are saner approaches to implementing offline features in your app.

Comment: @pvg I'm all ears.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic], this is too broad and opinion based for an SO question.

Comment: @pvg not sure it's too broad, I just got a very clear answer below.

Comment: Maybe, I guess it wasn't obvious from the question your notion of 'serialization' is a pretty odd one. Typically, object serialization, even in cases where it serializes full object graphs, does not serialize executable code. 'Storing just the data you need to restore the object' is basically 'serialization'. The 'too broad' bit is 'what's a saner way to make an app offline capable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot serialize functions, you would be better off creating a class that can be serialized and unserialized. Here is an example:

```
class Example {
   constructor(data) {
      this.data = data;
   }
   setKey(key, value) {
      this.data[key] = value;
      return this;
   }
   getKey(key) {
      return this.data[key];
   }
   serialize() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.data);
   }
}

const example = new Example({ foo: 'bar' });
example.setKey('fizz', 'buzz');
// save item in local storage
localStorage.setItem('example', example.serialize());
// see the stringified version
console.log('serialized', localStorage.getItem('example'));
// get the json out
const json = localStorage.getItem('example');
// create an instance of Example using the parsed json
const example2 = new Example(JSON.parse(json));
// use rehydrated instance
console.log(example2.getKey('fizz'));
```

Side note if you'd prefer to not define a `serialize()` method: if you add a `toJSON()` method to your class you can specify what you want to be serialized:

```
toJSON() {
   return this.data;
}
```

When you call `JSON.stringify(exampleInstance)` it will trigger the `toJSON()` method and will only serialize what `toJSON()` returns.

If you'd prefer to skip the `JSON.parse` step once you've fetched the data from localStorage, you could provide a static method that will give you a populated instance:

```
class Example {
   // insert rest of the class above here
   static fromLocalStorage(json) {
       return new this(JSON.parse(json));
   }
}

// same code as before
const json = localStorage.getItem('example');
const example2 = Example.fromLocalStorage(json);
```

Comment: So basically I would just store the data necessary to create the object from scratch? Seems like a good idea.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You serialize only the data and repopulate an instance of the object (with all of your methods) from localStorage